# D3.js circles order

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the follow json array

```
{"x" :"7","y" :30,"color" : "green"},{"x" :"8","y" :70, "color" : "purple"},  {"x" :"9","y" :50, "color" : "yellow"},{"x" :"10","y" :60, "color" : "black"}
```

but when i draw the circles, d3.js order the array by "y" parameter

Example : the correct order should be

```
    green -> purple -> yellow - black
```

but d3.js show

```
     green -> yellow -> black -> purple
```

snippet [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwunLycp/)

Comment: Why do you think it's the wrong order?  Check out your y coordinates.  (30, 70, 50, 60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 is displaying the circles correctly as the vertical order is based on their y value and not on their order in the array.

You're defining that here:

```
.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
```

If you would like to draw the circles in their indices order you could do

```
.attr("cy", function (d, i) { return i *10 + 100; })
```

Here I have simply multiplied their index with a constant (10) so that the circles will be drawn as you request.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwunLycp/1/)